# I am very old. Older than any of you here. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am very old. Older than any of you here.
>
> I show myself periodically, not always.
>
> I took birth at The Cradle.
>
> Very soon, I will make history.
>
> I have become the monopoly of the affluent.
>
> But, in the last two decades, the dragon has risen.
>
> Trust me. You guys know me. I am very prestigious after all.

This should be easy. Guess who am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is

> The Olympic Games

I am very old. Older than any of you here.

> The first Olympics is traditionally dated to 776 BC

I show myself periodically, not always.

> It happens each 4 years

I took birth at The Cradle.

> The Olympics started in Greece, considered the cradle of Western civilization

Very soon, I will make history.

> Rio 2016 will be the first Olympics in South America

I have become the monopoly of the affluent.
But, in the last two decades, the dragon has risen.

> I´m not sure but I think it is the monopoly of USA being beaten by China

Trust me. U guys know me. I am very prestigious after all.

> Well...It is!

Comment: Also, isn't a dragon a symbol of China or something?

Comment: @Mithrandir mm, a lot of Asian countries associate with dragons, perhaps not the strongest correlation to China

Comment: Perfect.... It was china(Symbol for Dragon)...